# Is there a way of finding out who cancel a Task?

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

I know it sounds strange but I am trying to do simple performance testing on our API and something cancels the request leading to errors in my application and failed responses.

Can I see who initiated the cancellation?

> 2018-03-12 14:37:10.656 +00:00 (BettingAPI)(BettingApi) [Error] exception thrown when executing fetchers, sessionInfo - "siteId: 1, customerId: 2231, sessionId: 1d01941a-829e-4ca9-ae69-45205b1f481c"
>   **System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.**
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at SBTech.Microservices.Client.Channels.HttpMicroserviceChannel.d__92.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at SBTech.Microservices.Client.Common.Clients.MicroserviceThickClient.<>c__DisplayClass7_02.<g__Func|0>d.MoveNext()
>
> **...**
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   SBTech.BettingApi.Services.DataFetchManager.DataFetchManager.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   SBTech.BettingAPI.Services.Flow.BetSlipAPIFlow.d__8.MoveNext()

I mean I can see the call in the runtime `ThrowForNonSuccess`, but can I realize somehow what caused it?

Comment: Add proper exception handling in your code. A task can be cancelled if the API you called threw an exception or there was a timeout, or the call was aborted. If you used  `async void` by mistake the tasks will be cancelled when the garbage collector runs to clean them up. Eg in a console application unless you *await* before exiting, the process will terminate, cancel all tasks and GC them.

Comment: If you want specific help post the code that caused this error. It looks like a call that started at BetSlipAPIFlow somehow resulted in abandoned HttpClient calls.

Comment: You can add [Ben.Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier) to your logging code or `catch` clauses to clean up the call stack of async executions.

Comment: Okay, will see what I can do, thanks for the suggestions, if I manage to filter the problem more I will put some code as well.